# Rotate image in RemoteViews?

Tags: android, imageview

I am creating an Android widget. This widget has a ImageView on it. I would like to rotate the image in the ImageView - is there any way to do this (without manually creating new images in a desktop photo editor such as Photoshop and including them in the app)?

Comment: You could ask the user to turn their head. :-) More seriously, I am not aware of a way to do this.

Comment: Are you looking to rotate the image as in an Animation?  Or do you want to have the image viewed at an angle sometimes?

Comment: I just want to rotate the image 90 degrees. It is a 9-patch image, if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this for an `ImageView` within a `RemoteViews`.  `RemoteViews` in general is very limiting.

If your images can be a static resource, you can make a `LevelListDrawable` in resource, and set each rotation as a level, then use `RemoteViews` to invoke `ImageView.setImageLevel()` with the appropriate index for 0/90/180/270 whatever.

If you are in a situation where you are drawing the image, you must re-draw it and re-send it to the `RemoteViews`.